Lombok 1.18.12 is not generating getter and setter in Eclipse 4.31.0
I have same issue as here but none of the solutions works for me in Eclipse 2024-03 (4.31.0) and Lombok 1.18.12.
I have dependency:
<project...>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
      </dependency>

I exit Eclipse and installed lombok in Eclipse:

I checked is it everything ok.
eclipse.ini file has this:
-javaagent:C:\Users\XXXXX\eclipse\jee-2024-03\eclipse\lombok.jar

There is lombok.jar file:

And I started Eclipse and Project/Clean all and Build workplace

And still lombok doesn't work.
I even update Maven on the project but nothing.


That Lombok version is ancient (it's from February 2020), so I would not expect it to work flawlessly with current Eclipse releases. According to the changelog, the recent v1.18.32 explicitly added support for Eclipse 2024-03. You should try that version and check if your issue still persists.

Ok, I solve the issue, but strange.
I put a new version in the pom.xml, 1.18.34.
When I tried to start lombok-1.18.34.jar (exactly the name in the .m2/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.34/ folder) downloaded by Maven it said it is corrupted.
Yesterday version lombok-1.18.12.jar wasn't corrupted.
So I downloaded the 1.18.34 version of lombok.jar (the name is without version) from the Lombok site and started that jar, then install/upgrade and when I opened Eclipse 4.31.0 I just Clean and Built workspace (all) and it works fine now.
Insane.
